How to handle a Beacon API request on page close without provoking 499 HTTP response?
Currently I am trying to send a Beacon API request to my backend whenever my web application is being closed while it processes data in order to communicate to the backend that it should not expect further data from the client. I chose to use the above mentioned API especially due to following description:

The Beacon API is used to send an asynchronous and non-blocking request to a web server. The request does not expect a response. Unlike requests made using XMLHttpRequest or the Fetch API, the browser guarantees to initiate beacon requests before the page is unloaded and to run them to completion.

This seems like the perfect use case for what I want to achieve. However, after implementing and testing this I found out that my backend (running on nginx) is returning HTTP 499 Client Closed Request instead of performing and completing the operations.
I understand why a 499 response is provoked but what I want to know is, if there is any way that I configure my backend to just ignore that the client closed the connection and go through with all planned operations.

have you considered fetch with the keepalive option?

Use appropriate *_ignore_client_abort directive. For example https://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_ignore_client_abort
